# Encoding corruption when moving database vía mysqldump

Tags: encoding, mysql

I'm trying to move a database to another server, I used this methods:

Any of this methods display weird characters on the website.

Using pipe:

`mysqldump -uuser -ppassword table | mysql -hhost -uuser -p table`

Alternative #1

```
mysqldump -u username -p --default-character-set=latin1 -N database > backup.sql
mysql -u username -p --default-character-set=latin1 database < backup.sql
```

Alternative #2

```
mysqldump -u username -p --default-character-set=latin1 -N database -r backup.sql
mysql -u username -p --default-character-set=latin1 database < backup.sql
```

Alternative #3

`mysqldump --default-character-set=latin1 -uuser -ppassword table | mysql --default-character-set=latin1 -hhost -uuser -p table`

The result is the same on any of the alternatives. The database is in latin1, wordpress site.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't Wordpress generally UTF-8 these days? (Edit: oh, it doesn't [seem to be.](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/12/26/wordpress-database-charset-and-collation-configuration/))

Comment: Well, the content is in UTF8 (generated by wordpress) but the charset on the database is latin1.

Comment: What about the charset on the tables? Can you try `--default-character-set=utf8` just for laughs? (Not sure whether it'll help, but always worth a try)

Comment: Here is the information from one table and database charset: http://pastebin.com/Z9GZYaLq

Comment: Trying with --default-character-set=utf8 ...

Comment: Same with --default-character-set=utf8. Econding problem.